# Evaluating the limit $\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \frac{e^n+e^{-n}}{e^{n+1}+e^{-n-1}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

How would you solve the following limit? It's $\frac \infty \infty$ and L'Hospital doesn't seem to help:

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \frac{e^n+e^{-n}}{e^{n+1}+e^{-n-1}}$$

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Hint**: Multiply the numerator and denominator by $e^{-n}$.

Comment: oh.. I'm an idiot. Thank you

Answer (score 9):

**HINT**: Divide the numerator and the denominator by $\mathrm{e}^n$:
$$
  \frac{e^n+e^{-n}}{e^{n+1}+e^{-n-1}} = \frac{1+e^{-2n}}{e+e^{-2n-1}}
$$

Answer (score 5):

Intuition: As $n$ gets very large, $e^{-n}$ and $e^{-n-1}$ both get very, very small, so what you're left with should be 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{e^n}{e^{n+1}}.$$